# Observables vs Promises - processing, then returning an async result

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs

I've had quite a bit of experience of working with promises in AngularJS, and am now trying to get my head round Observables in Angular.

I *like* promises for handling single asynchronous results - they seem like a very good fit for this use case - but Angular seem keen to use Observables for everything, so I'm now trying to understand best practices for using this pattern.

Below is an example of how I might achieve something using a promise chain. The objectives are:

1. `MyClass.value` should *always* be set when `doSomethingAsync()` is
   called
2. The caller - in this case `doSomethingElse()` should be able to chain off the back of
   `doSomethingAsync()` *if it wants to* and *wait until it's completed* before using the result

```
export class MyClass {
    private value;

    public doSomethingAsync() {
        return someAsyncCall()
            .then(value => {
                this.value = value
            });
    }
}

export class MyOtherClass {
    public doSomethingElse() {
        const myObj = new MyClass();
        let myValue;

        myObj
            .doSomethingAsync()
            .then(value => {
                myValue = value
            });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I would do this using Observables.

I could use `.pipe()` with `tap()` in `doSomethingAsync()` to capture the value, but the problem then is that this won't be executed unless `doSomethingElse()` calls `subscribe()` on the returned Observable. I don't want to make `doSomethingAsync()` dependent on what the caller does next.

I *could* call `subscribe()` in `doSomethingAsync()` to capture the value, but then I no longer have an Observable to return. So I think I would perhaps have to do something like this instead:

```
export class MyClass {
    private value;
    private valueSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

    public doSomethingAsync() {
        someAsyncCall()
            .subscribe(value => {
                this.value = value;
                this.valueSubject.next(value);
            });

        return valueSubject.asObservable();
    }
}

export class MyOtherClass {
    public doSomethingElse() {
        const myObj = new MyClass();
        let myValue;

        myObj
            .doSomethingAsync()
            .subscribe(value => {
                myValue = value
            });
    }
}
```

But this seems overly complex as I now have to mess about with Subjects as well and effectively have 2 different flows to keep track of.

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this? It seems to me as though this was a lot easier to handle with promises...?

Comment: `I don't want to make doSomethingAsync() dependent on what the caller does next.` This is **exactly** the point of observables and actually makes a lot of sense if you think about it. If there is nothing interested in the value (i.e. no subscribers) then why should `MyClass` store anything?

Comment: The `doSomethingAsync()` method fails to return a value because there is no return statement in its `.then` block.

Comment: @Adam I guess that using the promise pattern, a method can simultaneously satisfy 2 paradigms: 1) "Just do it!" and 2) "Do it and tell me when you've finished". With Observables this is no longer possible - a method can only really satisfy one or the other. It's possible that I just need to get my head round this, but at the moment it feels as though I've lost something useful...

Comment: Also - I'm somewhat annoyed that this question has been downvoted! I think I've done a good job of clearly presenting the issue. Whether I've fully got my head round the Observable pattern/philosophy yet is a different issue, but that's partly what the question is about. I'd appreciate it if someone could please enlighten me on this...?

Comment: @DanKing - I was an earlier adopter of promises, I felt like I groked them pretty early on, but I was late to the game with observables and it took me a while to get my head around the value of them over promises, or even how they really worked, (of which there are many, the primary one - I feel - is the one I pointed out in my first comment). Just go and do some reading about them. Something else you've got to consider is that Observables are more manual than promises, you've got to subscribe to them (same as promises) but you're also responsible for unsubscribing when you're done.

Comment: @Adam So I have an Authentication service with a `login()` method that returns an Observable so the caller can wait for it to finish. A side effect of `login()` (implemented via `pipe()`/`tap()`) is that the service stores the login details for later use. It doesn't feel right to me that this _internal_ side effect depends on something the caller does _after_ `login()` is called. It seems counter-intuitive that `.subscribe()`, rather than `login()` should change the state of the service. Promises don't have this problem because the login is triggered immediately. Any thoughts...?

Comment: Also - w.r.t. your first comment - if I call a method it's generally (if not always) because I _want_ something to happen. Why should I then have to call `.subscribe()` on the result to get the method to actually _do_ anything...? I'm genuinely struggling to see why this is an advantage? (and I have done some reading on this - presumably not enough - but am struggling to know where to look to find specific answers to these kinds of questions, hence the reason I have posted here...)

Comment: I think Observables make a lot of sense when dealing with multiple events, but am still struggling to see what (if any) real benefit they have over promises for single asynchronous requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured out how to do this now. However, I've now come to the conclusion (see further below), that this isn't really a good way to use RxJS...

```
export class MyClass {
    private value;

    public doSomethingAsync() {
        const observable = someAsyncCall()
            .pipe(
                tap(value => {
                    this.value = value;
                }),
                share()
            );

        observable.subscribe();

        return observable;
    }
}

export class MyOtherClass {
    public doSomethingElse() {
        const myObj = new MyClass();
        let myValue;

        myObj
            .doSomethingAsync()
            .subscribe(value => {
                myValue = value
            });
    }
}
```

## How it works:

1. Subscribing *within* `doSomethingAsync()` means the asynchronous source operation is always triggered.
2. Using `share()` means the caller can subscribe as well without re-triggering the source. `share()` uses a Subject factory under the hood, which also means that the caller can optionally retry the whole sequence.
3. Using `tap()` (rather than `subscribe()`) in `doSomethingAsync()` to capture the value, means it will be re-captured if the caller does retry - this keeps all the state consistent.

### Benefits:

1. `doSomethingAsync()` doesn't have to be subscribed to if we're not directly interested in the result - it will perform the operation anyway.
2. `MyClass` is responsible for maintaining its own state - the state of `MyClass` is *not* affected by whether the caller executes the `.subscribe()` function or not.

### Downsides:

1. It's atypical behaviour - Observers *usually* have to be subscribed to before they do anything, so it kind of breaks that expectation.
2. The state of `MyClass` *is* still affected if the caller retries the subscription - this is by design to maintain consistency of state, but it does mean I haven't *completely* preserved the encapsulation.

## Conclusion:

I have now come to the conclusion that the "correct" way to do this - without going against the grain of the way I think Observables are supposed to work - is in fact to rely on the caller to perform the subscription, viz.:

```
export class MyClass {
    private value;

    public doSomethingAsync() {
        return someAsyncCall()
            .pipe(
                tap(value => {
                    this.value = value;
                })
            );
    }
}

export class MyOtherClass {
    public doSomethingElse() {
        const myObj = new MyClass();
        let myValue;

        myObj
            .doSomethingAsync()
            .subscribe(value => {
                myValue = value
            });
    }
}
```

### Benefits:

1. It's less code than the previous solution.
2. Since the `doSomethingAsync()` method returns an Observable, I think the usual expectation would be that nothing happens until you call `.subscribe()` on the result.
3. It's retryable by the caller.
4. I think that in this context the returned Observable can legitimately be considered a "friend" of `MyClass` and hence able to modify its state (via the `.subscribe()` method).

### Downsides:

1. Still slightly more code than the promise equivalent.
2. Conceptually more difficult to understand than the promise equivalent:

   - Need to understand `pipe()`, `tap()` and `subscribe()`
   - Need at least a basic understanding of asynchronous stream processing.
   - For promises, you only need to understand how to chain single asynchronous calls together using `promise.then()`, which seems to me to be a much simpler concept.
   - Most (if not all) of the *stream* processing capabilities of RxJS are superfluous - and are just adding complexity - *if you're not actually dealing with a stream of events*.
3. Caller has to call `subscribe()` to make something happen, whether or not they care about the result (or completion) of the asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, they are quite keen on using rxjs. For a classic backend where you just want to call once, resolve a promise, and that's it, convert the observable to a promise and return your promise as your design demands; to achieve such thing, use [toPromise()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) from rxjs over the Observable.

The idea of keeping an Observable is, you keep observing an endpoint which keeps returning values in case the data changes and you recieve them on the fly, and whenever you are done, you unsubscribe (leaving the view or something like this). For example some api using websockets or some real time backend such as Firebase. But this would not make sense for a classic backend where you call an endpoint -> you get a result -> that's it. Because in the end, every time you want to get what's there, you have to make a new call.

Then your example would look something like:

```
export class MyClass {
    private value;

    public doSomethingAsync() {
        return someAsyncCall().toPromise();
    }
}

export class MyOtherClass {
    public doSomethingElse() {
        const myObj = new MyClass();
        let myValue;

        myObj
            .doSomethingAsync()
            .then(value => {
                myValue = value
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's an option, but then `doSomethingElse()` has to deal with a promise instead of an `Observable`, which means my application is now having to work with both patterns.

Another alternative would be to use `pipe()` with `tap()`, as I originally suggested, but call `toPromise()` at the end to create an implicit subscription, then use `fromPromise()` to convert it back to an `Observable`.

Seems like a rather unpleasant kludge though...

Comment: You seem to be arguing that Observables don't really make sense when you're only retrieving a single result, which I'm inclined to agree with, but seems completely contrary to the pattern adopted by Angular...

Comment: I just included in the answer how the code would look like. I can see this would not be messy at all, would look correct, and the framework would very well prepared for "modern" real time apis. There I would see the point why Angular did this

Comment: Converting Observables to promises via `toPromise()` seems to be fairly widely considered as an antipattern. Angular have chosen to go down the Observable route for HTTP calls etc., so this approach kind of flies in the face of that by re-introducing the promise pattern back into your application. One thing I guess Observables _do_ give you is much easier `retry` capability...

Comment: Hmm - except `doSomethingElse()` wouldn't be able to `retry()` anyway in my example, because `doSomethingAsync()` has broken the original Observable sequence and started a new one...